# With MRTK in Unity how can you detect the hand that grabbed an object? (i.e. left or right handedness)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, mrtk

Using MRTK's hand-tracking in Unity, I want to know whether it was the left or right hand that grabbed a game object. The game object has the NearInteractionGrabbable & ObjectManipulator components attached.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a hand is recognized by Hololens by checking if Left_HandLeft(clone) or Right_HandRight(clone) existed in your scene.
So if only one hand is registered, your object must be grabbed by this hand.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02XaS.png)

Comment: But, if both hand clones are in scene, I'm guessing this won't work?

Comment: No, it won't work. But you can check which hand is in grab pose, or nearer to the object. Now I don't have a better idea

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to read this post
https://localjoost.github.io/Basic-hand-gesture-recognition-with-MRTK-on-HoloLens-2/